# Get File Name Stored in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

Straight forward question :)

I have a column that is stored as such in SQL Server:

```
FileName    Attachments_21046_123400100473.pdf
```

I need to grab the last segment before the file extension, in this case, it would be the `123400100473`.

The last segment may vary in size of characters, so here it is 12 characters but sometimes it may be 15.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how many underscores come before the last segment, so I reverse the string and find the first underscore...

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(50)
SET @FileName = 'Attachments_21046_123400100473.pdf'

SELECT REVERSE(
        SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(@FileName), 
        5, -- Length of extension + 1.
        CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@FileName)) - 5
    )
)
```

Comment: The format is always the same, it actually is "Attachments_IDNumber_SecondNumber.PDF"

Comment: @RogueSpear00 Ah, well... I just leave it like this anyway, cause even if I know the number of leading underscores, it doesn't look any prettier.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson:  While this solution will work, and I do like the cleverness +1, be aware that it depends on the file extension to ALWAYS be three letters in length. It will file for something like .vb or .html or any other non-three-letter extension.

Comment: @PaulSasik Good point Paul... my answer is cute, but your code put into a UDF is probably the most robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve pretty easily this with a combination of T-SQL's [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) and [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) functions.

This is a little hacky but only depends on the presence of two underscores and a period. e.g. `%_%_%.%` The extension can be any length as well as the final substring:

**EDIT:** Updated to handle variable underscore occurrences:

```
create function udfGetFileNameSubstring(@val as varchar(50))
returns varchar(50)
begin   
    --declare @val varchar(50)
    --set @val = 'Attachments_21046_123400100473.pdf'

    declare @uidx int
    -- establish the index of the 2nd underscore
    set @uidx = LEN(@val) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@val)) + 1

    declare @pidx int
    -- establish the index of the period
    set @pidx = CHARINDEX('.', @val) 

    return SUBSTRING(@val, @uidx + 1, @pidx - @uidx - 1)
end

-- usage:  SELECT dbo.udfGetFileNameSubstring(col_name) FROM table_name
-- sample: SELECT dbo.udfGetFileNameSubstring('Attachments_21046_123400100473.pdf')
-- OUTPUT: 123400100473
```

The T-SQL could certainly be abbreviated, and I would wrap it in a UDF for clean use in your queries.

Comment: I was rummaging through some of the data, and there are some of the fields that have more than one underscore present.  However, those are records that I can ignore.  This wouldn't trip your solution, would it?

Comment: @RogueSpear00: It would trip my solution. I'll tweak it to handle the variable underscores.

Comment: @RogueSpear00: Pretty simple fix actually. Check the edited code

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT SUBSTRING(f.FileName,0,CHARINDEX('.', f.FileName)) AS 'last_segment'`

Comment: Your answer returns the entire file name.  I'm trying to get the last segment, please see what I had written under the filename example.

Comment: There should be enough there for you to figure this out. Look into the tsql String functions

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
DECLARE @a varchar(100) = 'Attachments_21046_123400100473.pdf';
DECLARE @b varchar(100) = REVERSE(@a)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, LEN(@a) - CHARINDEX('_', @b) + 2, CHARINDEX('_', @b) - CHARINDEX('.', @b) - 1)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format/length is always the same.. this might be the simplest.

```
select left(right(@Filename,16),12)
```